# Could I align/colour this form with inline CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a small signup form here http://violinschool.com/#join which isn't aligning properly. But as it's in third party software, I can't change a CSS file.

[image]

I'm wondering if I could put inline CSS there instead? The things I'm trying to do are:

- Make all the text white
- Put in a decent amount of space between the entry fields and submit button
- Put a decent amount of space around the field description text
- Make the entry fields and submit button a little bit bigger

Do you think this is doable using inline CSS?

Thank you so much for your advice!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What code do you have access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline styling will over ride any CSS so yes.

on the text you want white add

```
style="color:#fff;"
```

add margin to the bottom of your input fields, this should also create between you last field and the submit button.

```
style="margin-bottom:15px;"
```

also add this for space between labels and input fields

```
style="margin-left:20px;"
```

add padding to the things you want bigger

```
style="padding:5px 15px;"
```